# How to work with DropDownListFor in an EDIT view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I  have a problem with DropDownListFor on the Edit view.

Basically I'm using a partial view which contains my form and in my Edit and Create view I call this partial view.

I have around 5 similiar DropdownlistFor and these work well on create action but in edit doesn't, mainly i'm not getting (unable) to set the selected value.

In my Edit Action (GET), I fill my property ViewModel if the true object has the property filled.

```
if(icb.BAOfficer != null)
editICB.BAOfficer = icb.BAOfficer;


List<Staff> staffs = _fireService.GetAllStaffs().ToList();
staffs.Insert(0, new Staff { StaffId = -1, Name = "" });
editICB.BAOfficers = staffs;

return View(editICB);
```

This is how I'm filling my drop down and how I'm trying to set the selected value.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BAOfficerSelected, new SelectList(Model.BAOfficers, "StaffId", "Name", (Model.BAOfficer!= null ? Model.BAOfficer.StaffId:-1)), new { @class = "rounded indent" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BAOfficer.StaffId)
```

Comment: Can you post how you're building `Model.BAOfficers`?

Comment: I edited the post with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem setting a value to my  `model.BAOfficerSelected` in Edit Action, this was the (easy) secret.

I need the first item like a empty option because is not a required information, but on the edit view if has value I need to set it as selected option.

In the end, it was my code.

**My Model**

```
public int BAOfficerSelected { get; set; }
public SelectList BAOfficers { get; set; }`
```

**My Controller Create/Edit Action**

```
if (icb.BAOfficer != null) // only for edit action
 editICB.BAOfficerSelected = icb.BAOfficer.StaffId; //this will set the selected value like a mapping


//for Edit and Create
List<Staff> staffs = _fireService.GetAllStaffs().ToList();
staffs.Insert(0, new Staff { StaffId = -1, Name = "" });

editICB.BAOfficers = new SelectList(staffs, "StaffId", "Name");

return View(editICB);`
```

**My View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BAOfficerSelected, Model.BAOfficers, new { @class = "rounded indent" })
```

I hope this can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `SelectList`, I often find it works better to use a `List<SelectListItem>`.

Further, I usually use an `EditorTemplate` for my dropdowns to keep my views clean.

So if my select list returns `List<SelectListItem>`:

```
public List<SelectListItem> BAOfficers { get; set };
```

You can set it up like this:

```
model.BAOfficers = staffs.Select(staff => 
      new SelectListItem { Text = staff.Name, Value = staff.StaffId }).ToList();
```

Then in your `EditorTemplate`:

```
<!-- EditorTempaltes\DropDownList.cshtml -->
@model System.String
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m):
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, new SelectList(
        (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["selectList"], "Value", "Text", 
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model) ? String.Empty : Model), String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
</p>
```

And then in the view, just pass the SelectList into the `EditorTemplate`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BAOfficerSelected, "DropDownList", 
                new { selectList = Model.BAOfficers() })
```

Comment: How will I convert my List<staff> to List<SelectListItem>? I just can see it using looping but doesn't look nice use a foreach for read from List<staff> and fill List<SelectListItem>. What is your thoughts?

Comment: @CidaoPapito I've added an example of how to build the list using a Linq expression on your `staffs` object.

Comment: Thanks. I found a way to solve my problem, and posted it. I will test your suggestion and set as useful. ok? I need to learn abour EditTemplates so I can start with it.

Answer (score 0):

The best and cleanest way of doing this is setting the selected value in server side, in the `SelectList` object.

So, if your `BAOfficerSelected` is nullable... it is all simpler: You don't need to rely in adding a dummy item to hold the -1 for not selected value.

Instead, you do it this way:

```
List<Staff> staffs = _fireService.GetAllStaffs().ToList();
editICB.BAOfficers = new SelectList(staffs, "StaffId", "Name", editICB.BAOfficer != null ? editICB.BAOfficer.StaffId : null);
```

Of course, the `BAOfficers` need to be changed type from `List<Staff>` to `SelectList`.

Then, in your partial view you do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BAOfficerSelected, Model.BAOfficers, "Select one...",  new { @class = "rounded indent" })
```

Adding the 3rd parameter is needed to indicate that the default value (if nothing is selected) is that text.

Comment: Looks good idea but the condition for the selected value, has the following error.

`editICB.BAOfficer != null ? editICB.BAOfficer.StaffId : null`

**Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and '<null>'**

Comment: `BAOfficerSelected` need to be nullable int (`int?`). Can you change its type?

Comment: I changed when I saw the error but doesn't fixed.

The error is in **icb.IncidentCommander.StaffId : null**

Entire line;
`editICB.BAOfficers = new SelectList(staffs.Where(s => s.Role == RoleTypes.IncidentCommander).ToList(), "StaffId", "Name", editICB.IncidentCommander != null ? **icb.IncidentCommander.StaffId : null**);`

Comment: I changed to `editICB.BAOfficers = new SelectList(staffs, "StaffId", "Name", icb.BAOfficer != null ? (int?)icb.BAOfficer.StaffId : null);`. I did a implicit conversion using (int?) and partial works... I checked in view and I'm seeing the BAOfficers filled and has a Selected Value on. But the dropdrownlist looks not respecting it, because it's render with the "Select one..." selected.

Comment: Remove the code (icb.BAOfficer != null ? (int?)icb.BAOfficer.StaffId : null) and hardcode an existing int value... just to see it that work.

Comment: Could you check that in the constructor of your SelectList... the second parameter is the "StaffId" and the third is "Name"? In my answer I put them in the wrong order... now I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I found a way to solve my problem, and posted it. Really thanks for your helpfulness.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem ,too.

According the article https://dotnetfiddle.net/PIGNLF which way gave a simple way to deal with this problem without two Models or more classes.[enter link description here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PIGNLF)

here is my code

add model

```
public class NoteSelectLisModel
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

add Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? _ID) 
        {             
            ViewBag.NoteState = new SelectList(new List<NoteSelectLisModel>()
            {
              new NoteSelectLisModel() {Value="1",Name="A)"},
              new NoteSelectLisModel() {Value="2",Name="B"},
              new NoteSelectLisModel() {Value ="3",Name ="C"} 
             }, "Value", "Name", 1);  

            Table ut = _db.Tables.Find(_ID);   
            if (ut == null)
            {  
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {                                  
               return View(ut);
            }
        }
```

add View .cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NOTE, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.NoteState, "No Selected")
```

The edit's Model is the same and the dropdownlist passed by View.bag